# How to efficiently find if a list exist inside of another list python

Tags: python, list, search, boolean, processing-efficiency

I would like to determine whether a list of strings can be found within another list of strings in python.

For example:

```
list1 = ['iguana','cat','spider','monkey','dog']
list2 = ['cat','dog']

result = False

for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        if list1[i] == list2[j]
            result = True

print(result)
```

and the result is true, but this seems to cause problems on larger lists

Is there any way to search through the first list more efficiently with cleaner code?

Comment: Convert one to a set then use `.issubset`/`.issuperset` (depends on which one you converted)

Comment: I am confused, I am not familiar with subsets how do I do that?

Comment: You could try to use "set()" to check if there's intersection.

Comment: Thank you @DeepSpace I figured it out and it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question was specifically about lists. I am presuming you are trying to ascertain if all elements in `list2` are in `list1`. If so, then we're talking about sets, and then this would be a solution:

```
set1 = {"iguana", "cat", "spider", "monkey", "dog"}
set2 = {"cat", "dog"}
print(set2.issubset(set1))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is structure called set. It has very efficient functions checking if element presents in set or not. Also it has functions checking if another set is a subset of it.
For example you have two lists.

```
list1 = ['iguana','cat','spider','monkey','dog']
list2 = ['cat','dog']
```

You can create two sets from them, and check if all elements of list2 presents in list1 (if this is what you want) like this.

```
set1 = set(list1)
set2 = set(list2)
answer = set2.issubset(set1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give this a shot using list comprehension

```
list1 = ['iguana','cat','spider','monkey','dog']
list2 = ['cat','dog']

if [animal for animal in list2 if animal in list1] == list2:
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

or you can use `.issubset`. But it seems others have suggested that already.

Comment: this solution is O(n^2) and set solution is O(n)

Comment: ok... Thank you for providing this information.